# Asynchronous indexeddb

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, indexeddb

I want to do some things in asynchronous mode with indexeddb and i fail. Do you have an idea on my problem?

The code :

```
function test(basekey) {
    window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("base");

    var lConnection = window.indexedDB.open("base", 1);
    lConnection.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var lDB = event.target.result;
        var lTransactionGlobal = lDB.transaction(['person'], 'readwrite');
        var lTransactionTable = lTransactionGlobal.objectStore('person');
        var lRequest = lTransactionTable.add({key: basekey+1, name:"me"});
        lRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("Second wrote");
                lRequest = lTransactionTable.add({key: basekey+2, name:"you"});
                lRequest.onsuccess = function () {
                    lDB.close();
                };
                lRequest.onerror = function () {
                    console.error("Request 2 failed");
                };
            }, 0);
        };
        lRequest.onerror = function () {
            console.error("Request 1 failed");
        };
    };
    lConnection.onblocked = function () { console.log("Blocked"); };
    lConnection.onerror = function () { console.log("Error"); };
    lConnection.onupgradeneeded = function (pEvent) {
        var db = pEvent.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("person", { keyPath: "key" });
    };
}
```

When i call test(0) i've this error for the second "add":

> Uncaught TransactionInactiveError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction has finished.

I've tried with Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design point of Indexed DB: transactions attempt to commit immediately when they have no further requests to process. Requests can be made against a transaction directly after creation, or in the handler from an event from a previous request in that transaction. So you can't make further requests in a `setTimeout()` callback because (1) it's not an event handler from a request and (2) after you call `setTimeout()` there's no further work and the transaction would have started to attempt to committed already.

Here's a simplified example, with the numbers indicating the order in which things execute.

```
function myFunc(connection) {
  var tx = connection.transaction('store');
  // (1) transaction is "active" here, you can make requests.
  var store = tx.objectStore('store');

  store.get('key1').onsuccess = function() {
    // (3) transaction is "active" again here.

    store.get('key2').onsuccess = function() {
      // (5) transaction is also "active" here.

      setTimeout(function() {
        // (7) transaction is "inactive" here, and the 
        // transaction will have attempted to commit,
        // so this will fail.
        store.get('key3'); // WILL THROW
      }, 0);

      // (6) transaction will be "inactive" when this returns.
      // Since there are no more pending requests it will attempt
      // to commit.
    };

    // (4) transaction will be "inactive" when this returns.
  };

  // (2) transaction will become "inactive" when control
  // returns to the event loop here.
}
```

This demonstrates both cases: the transaction isn't active in the `setTimeout()` callback, and it's after the transaction has started to commit anyway. But you'll see the same behavior with the first case separately - e.g. if you have a long-running transaction (lots of async requests) and try and do something in a `setTimeout()` even while there are outstanding transactions, e.g. moving the `setTimeout()` right after (3).

You must break your work up into multiple transactions, or do all of the non-IDB async work first.

Comment: I was afraid of this Answer... Ok, thanks for your confirmation :(